# Highlight items older than X

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation, date-time, formatting

I have a list which 4 statuses. New, claimed, pending and completed. I need to highlight items which are in the new status for longer than 3 hours. I've read that using the =today() function isn't possible in SharePoint. Is there anyway I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter using a calculated column (call it Highlight) and putting in '[Created] + 3 hours'. Then you know that If [Created] is greater than or equal to the Highlight column.

Comment: How would I add two days and have it consider the time as well? When I did plus 48:00 the calculated field just rendered 1 for all items. But I'm concerned that if I do plus 2, that it will only look at the dates but not the time between them.

Comment: Most of the calculation formulas can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Specifically check out the "Calculate the difference between two times" section of that article.

Comment: How would I add 48 hours to a date. Anything over 24 hours doesn't work when I do [created]+"48:00"

Comment: I've come to learn that times and dates in general are tricky. SharePoint even more so as it stores all date and time values as the number of days since January 1st, 1900. So for example if you type in 15.5 in a date or time field it is converted to man 15 days and 12 hours from January 1st, 1900.

You might want to try the following (this gives you +48 hours from the Created column's timestamp):

=TEXT(Created+(48/24),"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM")

Comment: I was able to get it working by doing created+2